# Microcontroller and Inductor part placement on PCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-layers

I am laying out a very tight design (space wise) on a PCB. Due to space restrictions, I was forced to placed a microchip microcontroller on the bottom side of a PCB with an inductor on the top side (directly above the microcontroller). It is a 6-layer board, with the stack-up being the following: signal,gnd, signal, signal, power plane, signal. Will this be a problem for the microcontroller? The inductor is 33uH (PN:[SRP1265A-330M](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/b1f5e4c150ce488a3dfe248e034417fa.pdf))

Comment: Probably no, but it can depend on kind of current flow in the inductor.

Comment: You also need to specify the type of inductor and the kind of core construction it has.

Comment: Inductor: SRP1265A-330M @MichaelKaras

Comment: A part number for the inductor is not that helpful. You should provide a link to a decent data sheet for the part in your question.

Comment: https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/b1f5e4c150ce488a3dfe248e034417fa.pdf @MichaelKaras

Comment: If there is an inductor, there's probably a dc-dc somewhere close, then HF AC current flowing in the ground plane, which means... are you using the ADC on this micro?

Comment: It's a shielded inductor but there will likely be noticeable leakage from the inductor and the traces running to it and the capacitors and IC. Unlikely to completely screw it up but if the MCU has RF, ADC, touch sensing or other analog peripherals you might see issues.

Comment: @peufeu yes, we are using the ADC to measure voltage from a current sensor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, we are using ADC to determine the current consumption of another part.

Comment: Is the inductor for a DC-DC converter, or for filtering something like a power supply? I mean is the magnetic field high frequency AC or mostly DC?

Comment: I would think it would depend on what the microcontroller is doing and what the inductor is doing, no?

Comment: @be-ee That inductor is rated for 8A.  How much AC current are you pushing through this?  8A of current under a micro could be a problem.  One of the first places you may have trouble is the reset line.  The micro may completely reset occasionally.  Often we leave the reset line floating, or put a large-value resistor on it to pull it up.  This may not be sufficient in your case.

Comment: @scorpdaddy the max current pushing through would be 3A.

Comment: The inductor construction is not specified, but based on the shape, it is probably a torroid. Torroids contain the magnetic field very well. However, the current spikes in the traces may cause issues. Good layout techniques are essential.

Comment: @be-ee Consider: you have a 10k pullup resistor on reset to 3V.  0.3mA current to pull it to zero.  The "regular" current in the coil above is 3A.  That means you're looking for 80dB of rejection from the coil current to the reset trace on the other side.  60dB is doable.  80dB is very hard to achieve.  That doesn't include "irregular" current like surges and spikes.  Short answer: move the coil, use an active pullup on reset, separate power and electronics on separate parts of the board, and put a cage on the electronics.

Comment: @be-ee Your biggest problem may not be the inductor at all, but the traces to and from the inductor.  The field radiated in air from those traces may give you problems regardless of the inductor.  You need to get the 3A traces away from the micro.  Also your stackup may not be right for what you're trying to do.  Your power layer has to have a field through 2 signal layers to get to ground.  Minimizing the 3A loop area is crucial.

Comment: How close are all the parts together? Can you share your PCB design?

Comment: Hey guys, I just moved the microcontroller and other critical ICs away from the inductor.